# How to open internal storage files in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I want to open files into WebView. My all files saved in internal storage. I want to keep my files private. Files type can be PDF, txt and MS-Word etc.

I have tried using Content Provider but it not works for PDF and MS-Word files.

I tried the below code for open in WebView.

```
String doc= "<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+Uri.parse(path)+"width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
web.loadUrl(doc);
```

How can I open internally stored files in webview?

Comment: A WebView cannot display .pdf files or MS-Word (.doc) files. And an iframe displays html. It is unclear what you want.

Comment: You can use WebView.loadUrl( file..path ) to load and display files like html, txt and jpg. But not pdf and doc.

Comment: @blackapps I want to display pdf and doc files in webview using the google's doc viewer. is it possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible as you will know. What else is your posted code doing now than that? But the `url` query parameter cannot point to a file on your device as the google site has no access to a '`path` on your device.

Comment: @blackapps how can I do this? any idea? and one more thing files are stored in internal storage. so 3rd party apps can't access these files.

Comment: A third party app like a pdf viewer can display your pdf files as you will use a content or file provider to serve your private files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried using Content Provider but it not works for PDF and MS-Word files.

A `ContentProvider` works equally well for all MIME types.

> I tried the below code for open in WebView.

That is using an undocumented, unsupported URL for displaying **Web-hosted content** in a Google-supplied document-rendering page. That has no ability to access files on a device.

> How can I open internally stored files in webview?

For certain types of files — such as plain text, HTML, and some image formats — `WebView` will be able to display the content directly. Just use `loadUrl()` with the `file` URL.

For a few other types of files, you may be able to find third-party JavaScript that you can use. For example, for PDF, you could modify [Mozilla's PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to be able to work with local PDFs.

The only general-purpose solution is for you to learn JavaScript and write your own document-rendering code. Put that JavaScript (and related HTML/images/CSS) in your Android app, and have it open the local filesystem content using `file` URL values.